# OnItemClickListener of a GridView inside the header of my ListView sometimes does not get called after I scroll down and back up

Tags: android, listview, gridview, onclicklistener, onitemclicklistener

I'm implementing a Calendar feature in my app where I use a `GridView` for my calendar and this `GridView` is the header of my `ListView` which displays the day's events. Sometimes after I scroll down the `ListView` and back up (the header completely leaves the visible area), the `onItemClick()` of the `GridView` is not called even if I press repeatedly. after many tries, however, It starts working again.

What I checked:

1. Added an `OnTouchListener` to header view - that is being called, indicating it isn't some sort of UI freeze, and that the `onItemClick` is simply not being called;
2. Initially, I was using a custom `ListView`, changed that to normal ListView, so it isn't a problem with the Library
3. I believe that the `onItemClickListener` is not null as the click event occurs after repeatedly pressing the individual views
4. I do not, anywhere in my code, set any `Listener` as null
5. Checked the [EDIT: there is no exception, I just created one to see the stacktrace] StackTrace inside the `OnItemClick` there is no weird flow, I tried to do debugging at the system files to see at what point the flow is being broken, but android studio has some issue where it tells me source code doesn't match bytecode, so I cant follow the code flow.

   ```
   at com.a.CalendarViewFragment$3.onItemClick(CalendarViewFragment.java:370)
                                                                  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
                                                                  at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1156)
                                                                  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3147)
                                                                  at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4062)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6165)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
   ```

So what can be the issue?

My Code:

```
final LinearLayout singleMonthLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_month_view, null);
final GridView gridview = (GridView) singleMonthLayout.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
final CalendarAdapter adapCal = new CalendarAdapter(getContext());
gridview.setAdapter(adapCal); // the adapter for the gridview
 gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
                    if (parent instanceof GridView) {
                        int dayOfMonth = adapCal.getDayOfMonth(position);
                        System.out.println("gridView -> click "+ dayOfMonth +"!");
                        Log.d("-> StackTrace", Log.getStackTraceString(new Exception()));
                        // do stuff;
                     }
monthListView.addHeaderView(singleMonthLayout, null, false);
monthListView.setAdapter(viewAdapter); // the adapter for the listview
```

Comment: what is that exception you got?

Comment: I did not get any exception, I just created a `new Exception()` so that i could see stacktrace, sorry for being unclear

Comment: could you please post your code